# Remote Access remote pc using 2 USB

Tags: remote-access, remote-server, remote-desktop

I am not sure if this is correct but I did see an advert in the newspaper about secure remote access using two usb. One USB is  plugged into remote PC and the other USB plugged into the machine through which I am connecting from. It creates the secured remote access without any need of third party software like logmein or gotomyPC or any other commercial remote software.

Can anyone suggest if this is possible and if anyone currently doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 basic ways:

1. secure everything on your pc, by encrypting all files on it with USB
   dongle, for example [GuardKey](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016ZEF3ZQ) or any similar. Btw in China this
   method is very popular to keep files safe and no files leaking
   outside companies as file actions are logged (can't say what exact dongle they use);
2. make secure connection between computers by using [VPN tunnel](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2403388,00.asp)
   (very popular these days for users), no extra hardware needed;
3. For server is HSM (hardware security module) what can be as a
   [box](https://www.thalesesecurity.com/products/general-purpose-hsms) and is considered as military grade or cheaper solution USB
   dongle and on other end USB dongle or embedded chip capable to
   decrypt and crypt all in/out going data stream usually combined with
   KMS (key management software) what can be embedded in hardware or
   separate install-able.

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for your detailed answer. I think all three options are great but one which can be done free of cost is the VPN tunnel.

Comment: Hi Goaul, I found something which I was looking for but they are dead now. Do you think anything else is on the market who does this  https://www.amazon.co.uk/iTwin-Connect-Zero-config-Public-Private/dp/B00AZU3IMC

Comment: That looks like was some startup project what ended not working how it should, but looks good on paper.
Hardware solution can be replaced with software: https://gbhackers.com/share-files-anonymously-using-tor-and-onionshare/